# Is it helpful to have a captcha on a login screen?

Tags: authentication, captcha

I introduced recaptcha to the login screen of a system.

My goal was all about security things like dictionary/bots attacks or other thing of that type.

The users now hate it, Some did not even understand it  and I had to remove it.

When I look around, I don't see many systems with that on the login screen, most of the times on other forms like contact us or sometimes like in stack exchange when you want to post.

It made me wonder is it a good idea to have it on the login screen?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question: `The users now hate it, Some did not even understand it and I had to remove it.` If you need a captcha put it when a user is doing something (e.g. posting a message, transferring money) rather than just signing in.

Comment: As a point of information, [Register 365](http://www.register365.com/) have a CAPTCHA on their control panel login, so this is not unknown. (It's easy to bypass: just log in on the main site instead, then go to the control panel, so it's just pointless and annoying, but still, it's there.)

Comment: If your goal is to stop dictionary and bot attacks, just add a delay after a failed login: 1 second, 2 seconds, 4, 8, 16, 32, and so on.  A human who mistypes his password won't care about a 1, 2, or even 4 second delay.  A bot will be *pissed*!

Comment: @bishop What do you base the delay on? The username leads to a trivial DoS attack and IPs don't work so well either when faced with a botnet which consists of many zombies.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Not username. Typically I configure my IDS to throttle by IP on repeated hits to login and reset routes. This has worked for all attacks to date. Sure if there was a zombie net with 100k nodes, they could try 600k passwords in 60s with this back-off, but for a high value site I might use a 500% exponential back-off: 1, 6, 36, etc.  At any rate, this shouldn't be the only technique: mandatory 2FA or even 2FA informed by login failures would be A Good Thing.

Comment: Captchas are never helpful, they are always a pain. Just don't.

Comment: @codesinChaos If they have many zombies it's not a trivial DoS attack anymore.  I think one goal is raising the bar high enough so there is enough noise where an IDS can alert a human.

Comment: What's wrong with captchas? They seem to work fine.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The way I've seen some large systems do it is to only require a captcha after sequential failed login attempts (ie: reset the count after a valid login).  If you are worried about automated cracking, you could put the captcha at some high number of failures like 20, 50, 100 failed attempts.  Almost no legitimate user will see the captcha, but an automated attack will get hit by it.

Is it worth it to add this complexity?  Security and UX are trade-offs.  You need to find the correct trade-off for your risk profile.

Comment: `an automated attack will get hit by it` distributed one on multiple logins won't.

Comment: That's mostly correct.  The distributed attack across multiple logins will not get hit by it unless they fail N times for each login.  If you are worried that a given account can get cracked in under N tries, you need to lower N.

Comment: Although if only automated attacks ever see your captcha, then you might as well just ban them, instead of giving them a captcha.

Comment: @immibis: It may be difficult to distinguish automated attacks from legitimate users whose accounts are being targeted by a denial-of-service attack.  If Fred's account is being attacked, requiring Fred to answer a captcha may be much less of a bother than being locked out altogether.

Comment: @Cthulhu the OP can collate the login attempts across accounts and client footprint (ip, etc).

Comment: @supercat I was thinking of banning the IP address, rather than the user. (Also, make it a temporary ban; automatic permanent bans are a recipe for disaster)

Comment: @immibis Too many providers are using CGN. Blocking an IP address could potentially block hundreds of legitimate users. But requiring all users accessing from that IP address to fill in a captcha could work.

Comment: I've seen a few sites make it browser session specific, probably using something like a cookie to keep track. That way if it is distributed it wont matter as it is username agnostic, and wont affect other users who will potentially use that same IP.

Comment: Tumblr does this. After three consecutive failed login attempts, the login page will display a CAPTCHA.

Comment: @Epicblood Ah but then I can delete that cookie to keep getting more login attempts :)

Comment: We ban you for 15 minutes if you enter the incorrect password for the 5th time, and completely lock the account if it gets to 100 incorrect guesses.

Comment: @coderama So it is easy to DoS an account by hammering at it 100 times?

Comment: From a usability perspective, using an invisible CAPTCHA would mean that the users do not need to see it in order to login. Could this be a possible solution?

Answer (score 9):

A captcha on a login screen makes no sense. I'm not surprised your users hated it. The purpose of captcha fields on forms is to prevent them being submitted by bots. A bot should not be able to login through your login screen, as it should not have valid credentials. If a bot can guess valid credentials, then you need to increase password strength.

Comment: There is a purpose of using a captcha token in login forms - to increase security against credential stuffing attacks. A botnet with millions of valid leaked emails/passwords is among the worst dreams of an API owner.

Comment: With invisible captcha options available it now makes sense. It didn't 7 years ago. The op was clearly using one of those horrible distorted code types. I still maintain that they are horrible for usability.

Answer (score 5):

> The users now hate it, Some did not even understand it and I had to remove it.

This is where you'll have to make the decision between usability and security. Altough it is useful to have a captcha on your login pages, it's incredibly user unfriendly.

My best tip would to log every invalid login attempt to a database, and before authenticating the user, check if that IP has tried logging in X amount of times within the past hour.

You could also add some form of Cross Site Request Forgery system to every login page. This means that at every login attempt a hidden field with a token will be generated, meaning that an attacker would have to make two requests to try to log in.

Comment: Blocking by IP is tricky thing. What about users behind CGNAT? Not all IPs are static.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a Captcha or ReCaptcha is not a solution, it is merely an obstacle for both hackers and users.

I have very good vision with my glasses and sometimes I can barely make out the image text. I would imagine that someone in denial about their vision is going to be infuriated.

Everything you implement needs to have a specific purpose or else you just end up throwing pies in the sky with poo filling and these pies eventually land directly on your users.

Here is some food for thought:

**1**

Problem

> User accounts are getting hacked due to automated brute force attempts

Solution

> Accounts are now locked after 3 failed logins

**2**

Problem

> All user accounts have been revealed and a bot is now trying to brute force all accounts
>
> All accounts get locked within a matter of seconds due to 3 failed logins

Solutions? Plentiful, but did we even need to get to this step? Is this currently an issue?

Comment: Locking accounts after three attempts makes denial-of-service attacks very easy.  Requiring that accounts with multiple incorrect attempts submit to a captcha would mean that someone who wanted to inconvenience someone else by making bogus login attempts on their account could do so, but the inconvenience would be limited to that posed by the captcha.

Comment: "I have very good vision with my glasses and sometimes I can barely make out the image text. I would imagine that someone in denial about their vision is going to be infuriated.".  How do you know you're not in denial? 

Answer (score 4):

Another way of attacking this might be to install a "honeypot". This is an ordinary input field which is included in the HTML together with the login fields (username, password), but this extra field is hidden using CSS.

Typically, bots will try to enter text in all the fields shown in the HTML, so in PHP I checked that if the honeypot field were not empty - I would ban that IP.

(This was for a homepage for a skydiving club with a tiny admin feature to update dates when we are going to jump etc. I would not recommend this for sensitive applications)

Comment: Automatically banning IP's might not be the best approach, as users who cannot load your CSS or users who are simply joking around will get instantly banned.

Comment: It is correct that it has it weaknesses. However, due to the small user base for the particular site I made this for I found it OK.

Answer (score 3):

CAPTCHA systems are there to differentiate between automated bots and real users. Unfortunately, as you've noted, they aren't very convenient (in particular for disabled users).

Whether it's "a good idea" or not depends on your use case, really, although they aren't very efficient with user logins: they are not very useful to prevent password guessing attacks and implementing a rate limiter in the application is more convenient to the user while implementing a [TOTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) PIN provides better security.

Having some form of "proof of work" from your client might still be a very good idea if you're going to spend server resources for them and if these resources are limited. A typical use case for such query are system that will perform work for anonymous users (for instance, a web-based WHOIS application could use that to preserve resources).

Answer (score 3):

Think for a moment about what your captcha is trying to accomplish.  Here is the goal I can think of:

- Prevent a large-scale automated attack from breaking into weak accounts

Here's a way to do that which will probably make your users happier:

- If a computer successfully logs in (as Bob), set a cookie on that computer so the server knows that computer gets 5 free attempts to log into Bob's account without needing the capcha.
- If the computer trying to log in is from Bob's last known ip, give that ip 5 free attempts to log into Bob's account without needing the capcha.

The idea here is that mass password guessing usually happens from computers or ips that have not legitimately logged into the account.

This can probably be improved by combining it with ideas from other answers where you give a few "free tries" to accounts or ips.

Comment: No need to include a captcha field after the 5 login attempts, simply lock out the user for a period of time. All sites should include some kind of password recovery feature, so it should never be necessary for users to keep randomly trying combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a captcha after 10 or 100 failed attempts it useless, as most current bots have a deathbycaptcha account, and the API for dbc is really easy to use. So, showing a captcha every second time is a good thing, I think.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent brute force attacks, you would be better to do the following.

1) Ensure that passwords are complex enough. If given the chance a lot of users will use extremely simple passwords, like their name etc. Passwords should be at least 8 characters, and should include numbers, letters, and mixed case.

2) Lock-out IP's after 5 failed login attempts.

It may be worthwhile adding a captcha field to the password recovery screen. Make sure you include enough text to explain to users how it works.

Comment: Locking out IPs can be very problematic for customers if they share an IP (corporate users, etc.)

Comment: Yes, locking out IP's can be problematic, but it's unfortunately a necessity to maintain the security of a website. The lockout period need not be very long. Even locking out for 15 minutes will significantly hamper brute force attacks.